# Using StateRestoreListener with Spring Cloud Kafka Streams binder

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I'm going to use StateRestoreListener with Spring Cloud Kafka Streams binder. 
I need to monitor the restoration progress of fault-tolerant state stores of my applications.
There is example in confluent https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/monitoring.html#streams-monitoring-runtime-status .

> In order to observe the restoration of all state stores you provide
>   your application an instance of the
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.StateRestoreListener interface. You
>   set the org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.StateRestoreListener by
>   calling the KafkaStreams#setGlobalStateRestoreListener method.

The first problem is getting the Kafka Streams from the app. I solved this problem with using

```
StreamsBuilderFactoryBean streamsBuilderFactoryBean = context.getBean("&stream-builder-process", StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.class);
KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = streamsBuilderFactoryBean.getKafkaStreams();
```

The second problem is setting StateRestoreListener to KafkaStreams, because I get error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can only set
>   GlobalStateRestoreListener in CREATED state. Current state is: RUNNING

Is it possible to use StateRestoreListener in Spring Cloud Kafka Streams binder?
Thanks

Comment: You'll have to inject that property around the time where the properties are loaded into the Stream builder

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks. I thought about it, but I don't know how to catch time when Kafka Streams has CREATED state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by using a `StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer` that gives you access to the underlying `KafkaStreams` object. If you are using binder versions 3.0 or above, this is the recommended approach. For e.g., you can provide the following `bean` in your application and customize it with the `GlobalStateRestoreListener`.

```
@Bean
public StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer streamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer() {
    return factoryBean -> {
        factoryBean.setKafkaStreamsCustomizer(new KafkaStreamsCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(KafkaStreams kafkaStreams) {
                kafkaStreams.setGlobalStateRestoreListener(...);
            }
        });
    };
}
```

[This blog](https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/06/stream-processing-with-spring-cloud-stream-and-apache-kafka-streams-part-5-application-customizations) has more details on this strategy.

Comment: You have helped me. Thanks)

Comment: If it worked, feel free to accept this answer so that others who have the same question may benefit.